# Save the value from a click handler and use in multiple external JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been at this for a while and I've tried everything (and learned a lot of new stuff thanks to stackoverflow). The problem I keep running into is I can't seem to get the value from my click handler saved from my citations.js so that I can use it in main.js? I've tried using a function with set and get, returning the ajax call inside the click handler and a bunch of other things so any help is GREATLY appreciated,

I have three .js files request.js, citations.js, and main.js

Here's the code,

```
request.js,

function citeAjax(citationId) {
return $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + citationId +    
'?format=jsonp',
              jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: 'jsonp'             
         });
}

var promise = citeAjax(citationId);

citations.js,

promise.done(function (json) {
                 var linkBase = "http://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/";
                 var link = "";                     
                 var itemId = "";                    
                 var urlId = "";

                 $.each(json.items, function(i,item) {
                     link = linkBase + this.id;

                     $('#sbItems').append('<li><b><a href="' + link + '" id="idNum' + 
i + ' ">' + this.title + '</a> - </b>' + this.summary + '</li>');                    
                 });

                 $('#sbItems a').click(function () {                        
                     var str = $(this).attr('id');                         
                     if (str.length == 7) {                      
                          itemId = str.slice(5,6);
                     } else if (str.length == 8) {
                          itemId = str.slice(5,7);
                     }
                 **// I want to get (json.items[itemId].id) which is any id from the   
link that is clicked and then store it in citeAjax()**  


                 }); // END Click event    

}).fail(function() {
    alert("Ajax call failed!");
});
```

main.js,

I want to use

```
promise.done(function (json) {
   // do something with the ajax request from any id that's inserted into the url
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: since you are using ajax for the click event I would use .live if you are switching these items in and out not sure though.  .live('click', function() {}

Comment: Why on earth would you put the code for the ajax request in one file, and the function that parses the result in another file ?

Comment: @adeneo I was just practicing using promise.done() in a seperate file from the ajax request. I can put it back in the file, no biggie. From your statement I take it to not be a good thing. Problem is even when doing that I can't get the id from the click handler so that I could use that in a ajax request that will display information on another page.

Comment: @JamesDaly, not sure what you mean switching items in and out? I have a set of links and the json behind those links json.id returns a different id depending on which link is clicked. When a link is clicked I want to store the json.id so that I can use it in a ajax request again to get more information with that id. Hope that helps some?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using document.ready function in each JS file, and that would make your variable out of scope from the second file etc. Also, the files would have to be included in the right order.

Comment: add a parameter to your citeAjax call called itemid or whatever and declare your itemId globally and update via your if statement and when you invoke citeAjax pass it the updated itemId variable as a parameter

Comment: @adeneo, I actually took out the document.ready for that reason and just put the script tags for my files before the closing body tag. Also I've checked the order and it seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

1st I would recommend againt mixing your application view with the application model.

If you wish to get the data in citation.js, 1st bind the ajax data to your view using $.data(), for example, to $('#sbItem')

and then read it from there to citation.js

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? I'm going to look up $.data() but maybe you could explain how that works or what it does?

Comment: I hope you already solved the issue! I meant to say that suppose you have `<a id='hello' href='#somewhere'/>` and in file1.js you handled a click on this. on the click, suppose you wanted to bind say a image size to this then do it using $.data to make it `<a href='#somewhere' data-size='320x450'>` and refer $('#hello') from file2.js.

Comment: Also, if you want certain things to occur in a sequence please also consider using $.deferred and $.when to keep your code cleaner
[Sorry to not explain all this in context of OP]

Answer (score 0):

```
 var itemId = ''; //store globally in first loaded file
function citeAjax(citationId) {
//do something with citationid in here or your ajax call
 return $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink/' + citationId +    
'?format=jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: 'jsonp'             
     });
}
$('#sbItems a').live('click' function () {                        
                 var str = $(this).attr('id');                         
                 if (str.length == 7) {                      
                      itemId = str.slice(5,6);
                 } else if (str.length == 8) {
                      itemId = str.slice(5,7);
                 }
})


 //call again 
citeAjax(itemID) // itemID should be updated
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work?? I guess I'm still confused also, because if the click is made $('#sbItems') and I get the itemId and put it into citeAjax(itemId) how does it store that value? The reason I ask is because my next page will need to use this value. So how will the next script know what the id is?? It doesn't seem like the value is truly being stored still??

Comment: I'm going to update the question. The problem is the links on the first webpage all have different id's, so when one is clicked I want to take and store the id and then use an ajax call with that id for my next page to be displayed. So the ajax call has a variable url might never be the same.

Comment: Actually going to ask a new question with changes I've made concerning storing the value in self invoking function